# Xamarin Image control doesnt set Image source

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I try to set an image every 20ms from TcpClient as a Memory stream the Image source is not set in the Image control in Xamarin, I wonder if there is some sort of limitation the time that takes to set an ImageSource in an an Image control the output from the debugger,:
https://pastebin.com/8FgN5Rai

```cs
        private Task<ImageSource> GetImageAsync(System.IO.Stream stream)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<ImageSource> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ImageSource>();
            tcs.TrySetResult(ImageSource.FromStream(() => (MemoryStream)formatter.Deserialize(client.GetStream())));
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        private async void ReceiveImage()
        {
                while (client.Connected)
                {
                    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(new Action(async () =>
                    {
                        imageControl.Source = await GetImageAsync(client.GetStream());

                    }));
                }
           
        }
```

ok i got to set the image but then it says is not a valid image object

Ok i tried a newer version but the image in the stream isnt valid?

Image loading: Image load failed: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 10-10-FF-10-10-10-FF-10-10-10-FF-10-10-10-FF-10-10

Comment: is TrySetResult returning true?  Have you verified that you are receiving valid image data?  this is 50 fps - are you trying to stream video, or something else?

Comment: @Jason I checked and it returns true but about if it has a valid ImageSource I am not sure

Comment: write the streams to a file and then validate them with an image tool

Comment: https://gist.github.com/PontiacGTX/a329b8b18c24c0df2c50952ae5bf535d

Comment: why did you post code for a windows screencap?

Comment: @Jason ok I was saying the way i captured the image and how it shoudl be sent to the Xamarin app's tcp client as a stream...  I will try your suggestion

Comment: You could try to use `ImageSource.FromStream`. It would be helpful.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I am actually using it ```tcs.TrySetResult(ImageSource.FromStream(() => (MemoryStream)formatter.Deserialize(client.GetStream())));```

Comment: but the problem comes from the Image control which shows these errors https://pastebin.com/8FgN5Rai

Comment: i think the error is caused by the conversion. What type of the image stream you get from the TcpClient?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT i got this problem sorted but then some problem came trying to set the Image to a ImageSource ```Image loading: Image load failed: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 10-10-FF-10-10-10-FF-10-10-10-FF-10-10-10-FF-10-10``` as if the code I used in this link didnt convert a bitmap to a ImageSource https://gist.github.com/PontiacGTX/a329b8b18c24c0df2c50952ae5bf535d

Comment: Check the format of the stream you get from the TcpClient. And convert it to the binary would fix this issue.

Comment: I think it should be a difference between Xamarin's ImageSource and WPF BitmapSource @WendyZang-MSFT